# Package fails only when executed in Execute Package Utility

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, truncated

I have a simple package which transfers data from normalized to denormalized db.

It runs fine on Visual Studio 2015 against remote dev server which is SQL Server 2012.

But when I upload it to dev server and run it using Execute Package Utility
I get this error:

> Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

Things checked:

1. Checked the error column, it's the same type, length (`varchar 250`) & collate in source & destination databases.
2. Installed SQL Server 2012 SP3 on dev server
3. Googling this error I see it's typical to flat file import but I'm using OLE DB source & destination
4. Package was upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 and ssis project is set to run against SQL Server 2012
5. Redirecting error / truncate rows to a flat file yields nothing
6. Inputs & outputs checked with advanced editor, all are `[DT_STR] 250` & same code page

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Ssis sometimes keeps output column varchar (50) based on sample data from flatfile. So please check out output column width

Comment: Hi @niketshah90, checked output column, it's 250 length.
I'm using OLE DB source, not flat file.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, changes noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the advanced editor by right clicking the OLEDB Source and destination components. Check their datatypes and length. They should match.

Process :

On your source task ,right-click - > Show Advanced Editor - > Input and Output Properties - > Source Output - > Output Columns - >Data Type Properties - > Data Type /Length

Change ( Data Type /Length) in both source & destination in similar way as per your requirement.

On your source task ,right-click - > Show Advanced Editor - > Input and Output Properties - > Source Output - > Output Columns - > TruncationRowDisposition .

--Fail Component - To fail if truncation occurs

--Ignore Failure   - To ignore truncation error

--Redirect Row    - To redirect truncated row to desired destination

You can check the rows also to guess the reason, If they are still failing

I hope this could help you!

Comment: decided to implement row redirect again and this time I got results. Don't know why didn't last time.

The error is caused by an invalid character.
Thanks.